# use iPhone/iPod touch Wifi through Opera turbo

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, ipod-touch, opera

I'm a boarder at a school and some sites are blocked. I normally access these sites via Opera Turbo on my MacBook, but on the iPhone I can only use it via the Opera app.

**Is there any way to route this though the WiFi settings so iPhone/iPod apps will use the internet via Opera Turbo?**

Comment: Are you using the Opera Mini ?

Comment: The Turbo mode might not be allowed by your ISP.

Comment: Opera Turbo works fine on my iPod and Macbook - and yes, I am using the Opera Mini, but I want to make it universally available on my iPod so other apps can use Opera Turbo/Mini